# How to test a React Chrome Extension?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm developing a chrome extension with React. Everything works fine, but every time a change is made, I have to rebuild the extension with:

```
npm run build
```

...and then go back into my browser and load the extension with the build. This works fine, as aforementioned, but it's time consuming, and I feel that there's a better way.

I can't test in-browser because I'm using Chrome APIs (storage sync, etc.)

Is there any other way to test? Or do I have to build every time?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, still using npm to build then viewing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [rollup-plugin-chrome-extension](https://github.com/extend-chrome/rollup-plugin-chrome-extension).

```
npm init vite@latest
npm i rollup-plugin-chrome-extension@beta -D
```

Update these files

```js
// vite.config.js

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { chromeExtension } from "rollup-plugin-chrome-extension";
import manifest from './manifest.json'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), chromeExtension({ manifest })],
});

// manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Rpce React Vite Example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "action": { "default_popup": "index.html" }
}
```

Then run `npm run dev`

Go to `chrome://extensions` in your browser and drag the `dist` folder from your project into the window. Start developing with hot reloading.